# Use Parameterized constructor in some another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I have a constructor class with injecting dependencies in it:

```
public class Facade : IFacade
    {
        private readonly IService _Service;
        private readonly IServices _Services;

        public Facade(IService Service)
        {
            _Service = Service;

        }
   }
```

What I want is to use "`Facade`" class constructor in some another class I knew the below way to use it ...but I want to get rid of the thing "`new`" 
   while passing parameter i.e. `new Service(config)`.Surfing but didn't get some fruitful result how to use a parameterized constructor.

```
 var config = new ServiceUrl();
_Facade = new Facade(new Service(config))
```

Comment: You need to start learning about IoC Containers such as Autofac, ServiceCollection, Unity and CaslteWindsor etc. These containers are very well designed and implemented for the exact scenario you mentioned.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes i knew but i didn't find any way do you have any template you suggest for solving this issue

Comment: On a side note, I'm pretty sure capitalizing variables other than member static readonlies is agains the .NET style convention.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Although I do agree it would be good to learn about DI Containers, this only becomes useful after you understand the basics of IoC and DI by themselves, which does not require the use of a DI Container.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid combining ctor parameters with Dependency Injection. If you have multiple services using different configs it'd be probably best to register it multiple times with different configs using names and resolve the needed one afterwards.

Here's an example using Unity:

```
var someConfig = new ServiceUrl();
var otherConfig = new ServiceUrl();

container.RegisterType<Facade>("someFacade", new InjectionConstructor(someConfig));
container.RegisterType<Facade>("otherFacade", new InjectionConstructor(otherConfig));
```

And then you can resolve the required `Facade` either during registration:

```
container.Register<SomeClassTakingFacadeAsArgument>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<Facade>("someFacade"));

container.Register<OtherClassTakingFacadeAsArgument>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<Facade>("otherFacade"));
```

or with manual resolve:

```
var someFacade = container.Resolve<Facade>("someFacade");
var otherFacade = container.Resolve<Facade>("otherFacade");
```

You should be able to achieve this in any of the popular IoC containers.

If you are 100% sure that you need to pass config as a parameter and you don't want the multiple registrations, I'd recommend creating a `Service` factory.